# Find index of an NSArray by passing value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

Is it possible in an NSArray to find out if a given value exists or not in the array (without searching it using a for loop)? Any default random method. I went through the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), but didn't find much relevant.

Please also tell me about `valueForKey` method (I was unable to get that from doc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `containsObject:` method will usually give you what you're asking - while its name sounds like you are querying for a specific *instance* (i.e. two object with the same semantic *value* would not match) it actually invokes `isEqual:` on the objects so it is testing by *value*.

If you want the index of the item, as your title suggests, use `indexOfObject:`, it also invokes `isEqual:` to locate the match.

`valueForKey:` is for when you have an array of dictionaries; it looks up the key in each dictionary and returns and array of the results.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you want to use the `indexOfObject` method. From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

> indexOfObject:
>
> Returns the lowest index whose
>   corresponding array value is equal to
>   a given object.

`- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject`

> Parameters
>
> `anObject`
>
> ```
> An object.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> The lowest index whose corresponding
>   array value is equal to `anObject`. If
>   none of the objects in the array is
>   equal to `anObject`, returns `NSNotFound`.
>
> Discussion
>
> Objects are considered equal if
>   `isEqual:` returns `YES`.
>
> **Important**: If `anObject` is `nil` an
>   exception is raised.

Comment: Thanks for your quickest accurate response and edit(+1 for that), But CRD also described valueForKey, as I asked.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
NSInteger idx = [myArray indexOfObject:obj];
```

to find index of object.
And to check if object is there or not in array you may use :

```
- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSPredicate` to filter an `NSArray` based on `NSDictionary`

```
array = [dictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(key == %@)", value]];

if([array count]>0)
{
value exists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `objectAtIndex` and `indexOfObject` like this:

```cpp
[tmpArray objectAtIndex:[tmpArray indexOfObject:yourObject]];
```