# NSArray find index for value

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a simple NSArray, from which the user selects a value. This is then stored.

How can I then, programmatically, search the array for that stored value and return it's associated index (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: `NSArray`s don't have keys associated with values; they are just a series of values. Are you talking about an `NSDictionary`?

Comment: I meant index sorry (getting all PHP up in my head).. but sorted now!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find index of an NSArray by passing value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6133925)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this method of NSArray

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
```

anObject is object you stored before, then

```
[yourArray indexOfObject:anObject];
```

Hope that help :).